# Future of Coldfusion is secured or not?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am a software developer of having 3 year exp. in coldfusion.
May be this question is the most silliest one.
**Is there is any future of coldfusion ?**

Some points which force me to ask this Question

- Very small developer community.
- Coldfusion 10 looks not so impressive [Lots of performance related problem with this version]
- only 1.1 % share of CF in web application.
- Very expensive

I Just want to know the experience of different people about coldfusion future. 
Is it a good decision to continue as coldfusion developer / should I start learning some other technology to secure my future.
Please share your opinion on this.

Comment: It's off-topic here, but try migrating it to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a programming question. However:

1) Small Developer Community - True. But I think the community is pretty high quality.

2) I would like to hear more about what performance issues you are aware with ColdFusion 10.  CF10 was mostly a rework of its internal deployment on Tomcat versus the antiquated JRUN server. I have heard about various bugs, but most haven't affected me to be honest and Adobe does have a patching mechanism built into CF now, but it still needs work.

3) I think you can see a very low share in many different languages that aren't the big 2: .NET/PHP.  However, Adobe has reported that they've now recovered to 2008 sales levels for ColdFusion Server.

4) There are Open Source servers available in the form of Railo and Open Blue Dragon if the cost is an issue for you. Adobe also gives the developer edition of CF Server for free, and there are free licenses available for education/students as well.

Adobe has committed to regular release cycles and have committed releases/support for a number of years to come. But of course, that can change any time.

I think it would be best to learn another language, I would highly recommend learning JavaScript since it would be complementary to your ColdFusion skills and you could venture into back-end JavaScript programming using NodeJS

Here's an interesting article:
http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/1/16/what-if-cars-were-rented-like-we-hire-programmers.html

I think if you learn skills that can be applied to most languages, you will still be valuable as a developer and changing languages should mostly be a matter of symantics.  I recently watched both a Java and C# web development presentation and I was really smiling at how similar the languages were to my current knowledge... they used classes, ORM, tests, etc and I could easily see myself transitioning to any of those languages given a bit of time.

Comment: I agree with fact that a programmer can code in any language by investing small time on it.And thanks for the link :)